# Delete files and folders in a directory which don't match a text list

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Let's say I have a directory named `dir`. In that directory, I have these folders and files:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
file1.mp4
file2.mkv
file3.mp4
```

I have a text file named `list.txt`, which has these lines:

```
folder1
file3
```

I want to delete everything from dir that is not available in the list file. Meaning these will not be deleted:

```
folder1
file3.mp4
```

And these will be deleted:

```
folder2
folder3
file1.mp4
file2.mkv
```

I have tried:

```
for f in *; do
    if ! grep -qxFe "$f" list.txt; then
    ....
```

but this does not provide the result I want. Note that i not all filename have extension on the list.

Comment: Try `find ...conditions... -delete`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to avoid the loop, just save the files in an array.
using `mapfile` aka `readarray` which is a bash4+ feature.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: Just in case there are no files the glob will not expand to a literal *
shopt -s nullglob

##: Save the files inside the directory dir (if there are)
files=(dir/*)

##: Save the output of grep in a array named to_delete
mapfile -t to_delete < <(grep -Fvwf list.txt  <(printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"))

echo rm -rf "${to_delete[@]}"
```

checkout out the output of `grep -Fvwf list.txt  <(printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}")`

Remove the `echo` before the `rm` if you think the output is correct

Comment: how about `q` for minimal printing?

Comment: There will be no output from `grep` which is not what this script needs.

Comment: the output seems what i am trying to do. But i realized that i don't have all the files extension on the list. but this script matches full filename with extension. i have updated the original question, kindly take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
cd yourpath/dir/

for f in *; do
    if ! grep -Fxq "$f" /path/list.txt; then
        rm -r "$f"
    else
        printf "Exists -- %s \n" ${f}
    fi
done
```

In case you are wondering (as I did) what `-Fxq` means in plain English:

`F`: Affects how PATTERN is interpreted (fixed string instead of a regex)

`x`: Match whole line

`q`: Shhhhh... minimal printing